# Integral of $\frac{1}{6x}$ - $\frac{1}{6}\ln(x)$ or $\frac{1}{6}\ln(6x)$?

Tags: integration, logarithms

I am trying to solve the integral of $\int_{}^{} \frac{1}{6 x} dx$. I originally thought to multiple the top and bottom by 6 to do: $\int _{}^{} \frac{1}{6 x} dx = \int _{}^{} \frac{6}{36x} = \frac{1}{6} \int_{}^{} \frac{6}{6x}dx = \frac{1}{6} ln(6x).$

However, my textbook says to take out the 1/6 first and then integrate to get 1/6ln(x).

I understand why that's correct but where is the flaw in my logic? I don't think I'm right but I can't see how I'm wrong either :)

Comment: $\ln(6x) = \ln(x)+\ln6$. Please note the last part is a constant - this is an indefinite integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no mistake !

$$\frac16\ln(x)$$ and $$\frac16\ln(6x)$$ only differ by an integration constant.

> $$\ln(6x)=\ln(x)+\ln(6).$$

Comment: oh thanks!! That makes so much sense. How did you get the division to be 1 over 6?

Comment: @NathanielFernandes: just like you.

Answer (score 3):

Let me clarify your question. You have:

$$\int \frac 1 {6x} dx =\frac16\int\frac1xdx=\frac16\ln x$$

while using your method:

$$\int \frac1{6x} dx = \frac16\int\frac6{6x}dx=\frac16\int\frac1{6x}d(6x)=\frac16\ln(6x)$$

Why is it so? This reason is the hidden constant of integration:

They should be $\dfrac16\ln x+ C_1$ and $\dfrac16 \ln (6x)+C_2$ instead.

You can check both expressions are equivalent if they differ by a constant; indeed:

$$\dfrac16\ln x - \dfrac16 \ln (6x) = \frac16\ln\left(\frac{x}{6x}\right) = \frac16\ln\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)$$

which is a constant. Therefore both answers are valid, only if you include the constant of integration.